# How can I get the paste short cut to work again?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm using a Chromebook.

Command+V should be the shortcut for paste.

But when I press it, nothing happens.

I checked the shortcut list in preferences and it says that's the key combo I should use, but it doesn't do anything.

Any suggestions for how I could get that to work?

Answer (score 0):

File | Options | Customize Ribbon | Choose Commands From: All Commands | Keyboard Shortcuts: Customize | Categories: All Commands | Commands: EditPaste | Press New Shortcut Key: Ctrl+V | Assign

Comment: Thank but I'm on a chromebook. I tagged that but didn't mention it in the question. So I updated my question thanks to you.